# Where to find Quarkus run configuration in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, quarkus

Some time ago I used to run Quarkus projects in Linux as any other proyect, this means by clicking "Edit Configurations" and selecting "Quarkus (Maven)" as you can see in this picture:

[image: Old way]

But now I´m using Windows and those menus have disapeared:

[image: No Quarkus run configuration here]

As an alternative currently I´m running my Quarkus projects from Maven tab, which isn´t a fashion way:

[image: Running Quarkus Project from Maven tab]

So at the begining I thought this was due to a bug in [Quarkus Tools](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13234-quarkus-tools) plugin that I created a new [issue](https://github.com/redhat-developer/intellij-quarkus/issues/206), however that plugin does not offer such feature. Could anybody give a hand on how to run Quarkus projects as any other project? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run configurations are offered by this plugin: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14242-quarkus-integration
Looks like it is discontinued though, marked as "deprecated" and it's not showing in the Plugin marketplace (within IntelliJ) for me, so I had to install it via the website.

AFAIK there are plans for the official JetBrains bundled plugin to support it (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-228507), but it's not done yet.